# Comparing current time with a time of data enty in database

Tags: java, mysql, date

I have a database in which I have users with their info etc. One field is named "maeindat" and there is stored the date of the entry (creation) of that entitiy ( user )

Now I want to compare if current time is "smaller" than input date and if it is set current date into the field, but if date of entry is bigger than current date set date of entry into the field

`current date < date of entry --> set current date into the field`

`current date > date of entry --> set date of entry in field`

Bellow is the code I'm trying out...

```
String maeindat = rs.getString("MAEINDAT");

LocalDateTime currTime = LocalDateTime.now();

if(currTime.isBefore(maeindat)) {
    currTime = maeindat;
}
else if(currTime.isAfter(maeindat)) {
    maeindat = maeindat;
}
```

UPDATE:

```
String maeindat = rs.getString("MAEINDAT");

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYYMMDDHH24MI");
LocalDateTime maeindatDate = LocalDateTime.parse(maeindat, formatter);

LocalDateTime currTime = LocalDateTime.now();

if(currTime.isBefore(maeindatDate)) {
    currTime = maeindatDate;
}
else if (currTime.isAfter(maeindatDate)) {
    maeindatDate = maeindatDate;
}
```

Comment: You can't compare two different type like `String` and `LocalDateTime`...

Comment: Can something be done to compare them? Tried parsing string but still getting errors

Comment: Search a bit here you have an answer to [convert String in LocalDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42763103/convert-string-yyyy-mm-dd-to-localdatetime). I advise you to use `System.out.println()` to see the value you convert too.

Comment: What is the value in `maeindat`? How are you parsing it? and which errors are you getting?

Comment: For some reason I cant insert it as code in the coment... at the moment I have "The method isAfter(String) is undefined for the type String" because isBefore can't accept string...

Comment: I have added an update to my question, will try that code and confirm if it works...

Comment: Use `rs.getObject("MAEINDAT", LocalDateTime.class)` to get a `LocalDateTime` from the database so you can compare it to the current time (just requires JDBC 4.2 (or later)).

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

Comparing a `LocalDateTime` with current moment makes no sense logically.

```
myResultSet.getObject(
    … ,
    Instant.class            // Retrieve from database column of type similar to SQL-standard `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.
).isBefore( Instant.now() )  // Or `isAfter` or `equals` or combine with `!` (meaning NOT before/after).
```

## Apples & Oranges

You cannot compare strings to date-time objects.  Parse your strings into date-time objects, and *then* you may compare.

## `LocalDateTime`

The `LocalDateTime` class lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. Use this class only if using a column in your database of a type similar to SQL-standard `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`.

This type is *not* intended to represent actual moments, specific points on the timeline. Instead this type is only a rough idea of potential moments spread over a range of about 26-27 hours.

If we say "Santa delivers the toys just after midnight on December 25th", do we mean just after midnight in Auckland, New Zealand or do we mean midnight in Kolkata India which occurs hours later? Or Paris France even more hours later? "Midnight" has no real meaning until you specify Auckland, Kolkata, or Paris.

**Comparing a `LocalDateTime` to the current moment makes no sense!** The `LocalDateTime` has no real meaning without the context of a time zone or offset. If you know for certain of an appropriate time zone for that value, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`. At that point, you have an actual moment, a point on the timeline.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = myLocalDateTime.atZone( z ) ;  // Converting vague idea about potential moments into an actual moment, a specific point on the timeline.
```

## `Instant`

If you intend to represent actual moments, use SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` and Java type `Instant` (UTC) or possibly `ZonedDateTime`.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

Capture the current moment in UTC.

```
Instant instantNow = Instant.now() ;  // Current moment in UTC.
```

Compare using `isBefore`, `isAfter`, `equals`.

```
boolean targetPassed = instant.isAfter( instantNow ) ;
```

## Smart objects, not dumb strings.

With a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) complying with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) and later, you may directly exchange *java.time* objects with your database. No need for converting to/from strings.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ; // For database column of type like `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`.
```

Or…

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ; // For database column of type like `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).