# create javascript Date object from string YYYY-MM-DD in local timezone

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have built an application that is using pure javascript Date objects and [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) for formatting and manipulating the objects.

The application functions perfectly in GMT where I developed it however I'm now on the West Coast of The States and I've discovered that many of my date objects are thrown out because of the timezone difference.

I am creating date objects from strings, either just `YYYY-MM-DD` or `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm`, for example `new Date('2018-01-19')` or `new Date('2018-01-19 08:00')`.

The issue is that when I create a date from a string of the format `YYYY-MM-DD` it creates the object disregarding the local timezone.

```
const date1 = new Date('2018-01-19');
const date2 = new Date('2018-01-19 00:00');

const dateString1 = format(date1, 'YYYY-MM-DD');     // gives '2018-01-18'
const dateString2 = format(date2, 'YYYY-MM-DD');     // gives '2018-01-19'
```

The behaviour is not consistent depending on whether you pass a time or not. If you pass a time then the date object is fixed to the local timezone, but if you don't then it is fixed to UTC. What I would like is that if I pass a datestring without the time (just year, month and day) that it would also create a date object assuming that it would be the start of the day in the local timezone.

Why is this? And do I just have to set the time as `00:00` each time I create a Date object?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse YYYY-MM-DD dates using the local timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893896/parse-yyyy-mm-dd-dates-using-the-local-timezone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## "Why is this?"

From [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date): "*Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in that date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, not local.*"

Parsing dates from strings isn't really advised; the recommendation is to do it manually by splitting the string and using the individual components as parameters. Or use a date library.

Comment: Sweet. Thanks for that. I wonder why they decided on this? It's not consistent behaviour... Anyway, I have created a little helper function that I pass the date string to when creating date objects and it simply tacks on a 00:00 on the end of the string if required: `return new Date(dateString.length > 10 ? dateString : `${dateString} 00:00`)`. Seems to be doing the trick :-)